# No transcription is showing on console Twilio and flask

Tags: python, flask, twilio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I am trying to build a system where the user will call on my Twilio number and user will speak after the user speak system will transcript it and paste it on console, below is the code which i have tried

```
  import os
from flask import Flask, request
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
import speech_recognition as sr
import contextvars

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True  # Enable debug mode

# Set up context variable for storing transcriptions
transcriptions = contextvars.ContextVar('transcriptions')

@app.route("/twilio", methods=['POST'])
def twilio():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    gather = VoiceResponse().gather(input='speech', timeout=5, action='/process-response')
    gather.say("Please say your prompt after the beep.")
    resp.append(gather)
    resp.record(maxLength=5, action='/process-response', timeout=5)

    return str(resp)

@app.route("/process-response", methods=['POST'])
def process_response():
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    audio_file = request.files.get('RecordingUrl')  # Get the audio file from the request

    if audio_file:
        audio_path = "audio.wav"
        audio_file.save(audio_path)

        # Convert speech to text using SpeechRecognition
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

        with sr.AudioFile(audio_path) as source:
            audio = recognizer.record(source)

        try:
            prompt = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)  # Use Google Speech Recognition
            transcriptions.get().append(prompt)  # Store the transcription in the context variable
            print(f"Transcription: {prompt}")  # Print the transcription to the console
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("Speech recognition could not understand audio")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print(f"Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service: {e}")

    resp.redirect('/twilio')  # Redirect to ask for more speech

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Initialize the context variable with an empty list
    transcriptions.set([])

    app.run(host="0.0.0.0")
```

but its not showing anything in console but responding with 200 code

```
>   * Restarting with stat  * Debugger is active!  * Debugger PIN:
> 219-507-781
> 3.89.252.195 - - [21/May/2023 10:22:01] "POST /twilio HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 44.211.172.28 - - [21/May/2023 10:22:15] "POST /process-response HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 54.198.17.35 - - [21/May/2023 10:22:15] "POST /twilio HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 54.224.196.243 - - [21/May/2023 10:22:28] "POST /process-response HTTP/1.1" 200 -
> 52.87.204.216 - - [21/May/2023 10:22:29] "POST /twilio HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Which tutorial did you followed? Have you called on your twillio number?

Comment: i followed some youtube video and chatgpt